# Deploying multiple DLLs

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, dll

Say I have multiple DLLs: d1.dll, d2.dll ... d10.dll. All of them are in the same folder. I also point to that folder in my environment->path. The question is: is there a way I can write a `master.dll`, which, when deployed, will deploy d1.dll ... d10.dll? The `master.dll` may be something trivial, giving only version info of my software, but its main task would be to deploy the other DLLs.

I am developing in C++ Visual Studio 2010 on Windows. How do I write this `master.dll`? It would be kind to explain in detail.

Comment: What does "deploy" mean in this context?

Comment: to deploy: since this is an excel addin. i drag and drop my dll's into excel. i have to do it for each of the 10 seperate dll's. what i want to achieve is drag and drop only the master.dll and as a result all the different function in each of the 10 dlls gets exposed (as if i have dragged and dropped them in excel manually)

Comment: Why don't you write an installer?

Comment: i do not know how to. can you please point me to some reference. I am new to this and do not understand the full mechanics of this process.

Comment: If the application is currently under development and you won't want to have to mess around with an installer every time you update, you might consider writing a **Post Build Step**. Have a look in the project property sheet under "Custom Build Steps" (or possible "Events" instead of "Steps").

Comment: As how to create an installer, check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c(v=vs.100).aspx, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2009/12/14/building-setup-and-deployment-packages-in-vs-2010.aspx